Character Controller Pro shakes on both host and client using Photon Fusion
I'm using Character Controller Pro in a multiplayer game built with Photon Fusion. The plugin works well for player animations like movement, rotation, and crouch, but I’m facing an issue with player movement in multiplayer mode.
Both the host and client are experiencing shaking when running. I believe this might happen because movement calculations are being performed on both the client and host sides, whereas they should only be executed on the host side. However, I’m unsure how to disable these calculations on the client side using Character Controller Pro.
Could anyone please guide me on how to set up this plugin correctly for multiplayer with Photon Fusion, particularly for handling movement calculations only on the host side?

Have you taken a look at the example projects that are provided and how they set up the movement? https://doc.photonengine.com/fusion/current/game-samples/fusion-impostor seems like a close fit for multiplayer photon fusion movement
